# monerod get stuck while loading blockchain from folder, but only offline!

Tags: monerod, lmdb, offline-nodes

I know that this should work, because I did this a while ago, but it doesn't. It opens as usual till "Loading blockchain from folder C:.....", But it works when I turn the internet back on. Is there anything I can do?

Comment: Try adding the --offline flag.